# Python numpy slice notation (comma vs index) performance difference?

Tags: python, numpy, performance, slice

Is there a difference in performance between using a comma and index references, even though both produce the same results? The latter may be more understandable for some conventional readers.

```
x = numpy.array([[1,2,3,4],
                 [5,6,7,8]])

comma_method = x[0,1:3] 
>>> numpy.array([2,3])

index_method = x[0][1:3]
>>> numpy.array([2,3])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much always go for the comma, not for performance reasons, but because indexing twice isn't quite equivalent:

```
In [2]: x = numpy.array([[0, 1], [2, 3]])

In [3]: x[:1, :1]
Out[3]: array([[0]])

In [4]: x[:1][:1]
Out[4]: array([[0, 1]])
```

That said, the comma also appears to have a speed advantage:

```
In [7]: %timeit x[0][0]
The slowest run took 25.41 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that a
n intermediate result is being cached 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 357 ns per loop

In [8]: %timeit x[0, 0]
The slowest run took 41.92 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that a
n intermediate result is being cached 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 148 ns per loop
```

I'm not sure what's up with the slowest run and the fastest run having such a time difference.

Comment: is there a link to documentation that details the former difference you mentioned between comma and indexing twice? googling `comma vs indexes` isnt exactly the most descriptive solution

Comment: @AlanL: I'm not aware of a documentation page describing it, but it's a straightforward consequence of the basic indexing rules. In `x[:1, :1]`, the indexing expression says to slice along the first and second axes of `x`. In contrast, `x[:1][:1]` says to slice along the first axis of `x`, then slice along the first axis of the result.

Answer (score 0):

The second case is less efficient as a new temporary array is created after the first index that is subsequently indexed.