# What is the difference in NumPy between [:][:] and [:,:]?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I am quite familiar with python programming but I found some strange cases where the following two lines of code provided different results (assuming that the two arrays are 2-dimensional):

```
A[:][:] = B[:][:]
```

and

```
A[:,:] = B[:,:]
```

I am wondering if there is any case, explication.

Any hint?

Example :

```
>>> x = numpy.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
>>> x
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
>>> x[1][1]
4                 # expected behavior
>>> x[1,1]
4                 # expected behavior
>>> x[:][1]
array([3, 4])     # huh?
>>> x[:,1]
array([2, 4, 6])  # expected behavior
```

Comment: One of them is a multidimensional list, the other is a jagged list.  See https://www.ict.social/python/basics/multidimensional-lists-in-python

Comment: @RobertHarvey the question is about `numpy.ndarray` objects, really, you cant' know the type of object just from this, and in any case, python lists do not have "dimensions".

Comment: Well, alright.  But that's not what the question is asking.

Comment: @RobertHarvey well, the issue isn't jagged vs not, numpy.ndarray objects implement true multidimensional arrays, and cannot be jagged. That link is really bad, giving a lot of misleading impressions that it tries to pass off as not mere useful abstractions but "how things are implemented technically".

Comment: Is the question answerable in its present form?

Comment: Closely related (includes example where behavior differs): [python numpy slice notation (COMMA VS STANDARD INDEX)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35644847/364696). Also: [Why does indexing numpy arrays with brackets and commas differ in behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38113994/364696)

Comment: Thanks! This latter really explains the phenomenon.

Comment: Note that `x[:][:][:][:][:][:][:][:][:][:][:][:][:][:][:][:] == x`. This just creates copies of x over and over.

Comment: Regarding the first part, can you provide any examples where `A[:][:] = B[:][:]` and `A[:,:] = B[:,:]` do give different results? I am not able to reproduce this.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a step back. Try this:

```
>>> x = np.arange(6)

>>> x
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

>>> x[:]
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

>>> x[:][:]
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

>>> x[:][:][:][:][:][:][:][:][:][:]
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

It looks like `x[:]` is equal to `x`. (Indeed, `x[:]` creates a copy of `x`.)

**Therefore, `x[:][1] == x[1]`.**

---

Is this consistent with what we should expect? Why should `x[:]` be a copy of `x`? If you're familiar with slicing, these examples should clarify:

```
>>> x[0:4]
array([0, 1, 2, 3])

>>> x[0:6]
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

>>> x[0:]
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

>>> x[:]
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

We can omit the `0` and `6` and numpy will figure out what the maximum dimensions are for us.

---

Regarding the first part of your question, to create a **copy** of `B`, you can do any of the following:

```
A = B[:, :]
A = B[...]
A = np.copy(B)
```